# How to read txt file that include both integer and special character in C++

Tags: c++

i have a example.txt file like this:

```
{2,red,3}
{4,blue,5}
```

So, how to read this example.txt file. I've tried:

```
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("example.txt");
int x, y;
char c;
string color;
for(int  i = 0; i<2; i++)
{
    ifs>>c>>x>>c>>color>>c>>y>>c;   // each c take { and ,
}
```

But it's not work.It sound like a problem about read char variable from txt file.
Any solution for this please. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem?

Comment: Use `readline()` to read an entire line into string then parse it. BTW it looks like JSON format to me.

Comment: Reading a string with `ifs>>color` will read up until next whitespace. The next whitespace is newline character, so after first iteration `color` will be equal to `red,3}` and the renaming reads will get moved.

Comment: @rustyx JSON strings are quoted `"`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you 're quiet right. How can i fix it ?

Comment: @SơnHoàng In my answer, I explained how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
ifstream ifs("example.txt",ifstream::in);
string temp;
vector<tuple<int,string,int>> data;
while(x.good())
{
    getline(ifs,temp);
    int a=atoi(temp.substr(1,temp.find(",")-1));
    temp.erase(0,temp.find(",")+1);
    string b=temp.substr(0,temp.find(","));
    temp.erase(0,temp.find(",")+1);
    temp.erase(temp.length()-1,1);
    int c=atoi(temp.c_str());
    data.push_back(forward_as_tuple(a,b,c));
}
x.close();
```

You can try making such string manipulations. Then you can reach all values in `data`